# Numbering polyline into polygon using Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql

I use a code that numbering (in a row *new_ID*) each polygon that is crossed by a polyline. For every polyline entity, the numbering is reset from 1.

```
SELECT 
   geometry, 
   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by line_ID order by line_pcent) as new_ID 
FROM (
    SELECT pp.*,
       st_maxX(ll.geometry) line_ID,
       ST_Line_Locate_Point(ll.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(ll.geometry, pp.geometry))) as line_pcent
    FROM pp
    JOIN ll on st_intersects(ll.geometry, pp.geometry)
)
```

It works but I would like to add another row *polyline_row* in which I need the numbering of polylines.

- When the first polyline cross some polygons, these polygons have *1* in their *polyline_row*
- When the second polyline cross some polygons, these polygons have *2* in their *polyline_row*
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found by myself :

```
SELECT
  geometry,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY line_ID ORDER BY line_pcent) AS new_ID,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY line_ID) AS polyline_row
FROM (
  SELECT
    pp.*,
    st_maxX(ll.geometry) line_ID,
    ST_Line_Locate_Point(ll.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(ll.geometry, pp.geometry))) AS line_pcent
  FROM pp
  JOIN ll ON st_intersects(ll.geometry, pp.geometry)
) AS subquery;
```